# Django dynamic url parameters

Tags: django

I'm trying to make an example for a product page where people can put designs on their product's. I'm using django and try to make my "designer" page behave differently on the type of product selected.

I want to have it behave like [www.mysite.com/designer/foo](http://www.mysite.com/designer/foo)
where foo is the name of the product

I have gotten to make it work like [www.mysite.com/designer?product=foo](http://www.mysite.com/designer?product=foo)
but i like the simplicity of the first url more and i can't imagine that wouldn't be possible.

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', overview, name='overview'),
    path('designer/', designer, name='designer'),
    path('administration/', administration, name='administration'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

my url patterns are like this, i've tried fiddling around with some examples using regex behind the "/" after designer. but i can't get it to work, the server keeps trowing

Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/designer/exampleA

I'm afraid i don't know where to start looking and how to properly formulate my question as webdeveloping is quite new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify a pattern `<str:designer>` where we make use of the [`<str:…>` path converter <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/topics/http/urls/#path-converters):

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', overview, name='overview'),
    path('designer/<str:designer>/', designer, name='designer'),
    path('administration/', administration, name='administration'),
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
]
```

Then your `designer` view function should take `designer` as parameter and handle this, so:

```
def designer(request, designer):
    # …
```

here `designer` is a string, so this will be *`'foo'`* if you visit `/designer/foo/`.